# How to remove character from every class in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have an Angular 4 app that includes a "/" for every .inner-page class in a html element.

For example:

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="inner-page /login">
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="inner-page /register">
```

I want to remove the "/" character so it should look like:

```
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="inner-page login">
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="inner-page register">
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I am looking for a jquery code to remove "/" occurence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split (`.split()`) the class attribute (`.attr()`) values by the character in question then rejoin (`.join()`) them.

**Code Snippet Demonstration:**

```js
$('.inner-page').each(function(){
  var elClass = $(this).attr('class').split(' /').join(' ');
  console.log(elClass);
  $(this).attr('class', elClass);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="inner-page /login">Login</div>
<div _ngcontent-c0="" class="inner-page /register">Register</div>
```

**Reference:**

1. `.split()` <sup>[Ref - Javascript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)</sup>
2. `.attr()` <sup>[Ref - jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/attr/)</sup>
3. `.join()` <sup>[Ref - Javascript MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code :

```
 var value;
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".inner-page").each(function() {
        value = $(this).attr("class").replace("/", "");
        $(this).attr("class", value);
    });
 });
```